# CakePHP's $this->data

Tags: cakephp, parameters, methods

I have an application the is loaded with forms in every view.  I've become rather familiar with CakePHP's array syntax and I use the $this->data parameter a lot.

I fell in love with skinny controllers and fat models, so I put as much code in my models as is possible.  Unless I'm doing something complex, most of my controller methods look like this:

```
function some_action() {
    $this->set('data', $this->Model->some_action($this->data));
}
```

Then, in my Model, I have a method that takes one parameter:

```
function some_action($this_data = NULL) {
    // do some stuff, manipulate the data etc.
    $this->create();
    if ($this->save($this_data)) {
        // return success message here
    }
}
```

I've oversimplified, but you get the idea.

My question:  I always send $this->data to my model and catch it with a variable, $this_data.  However, I was wondering if this is one step too many?  Does the Model inherit $this->data?  If so, could I change the above controller method to this:

```
function some_action() {
    $this->set('data', $this->Model->some_action());
}
```

And then manipulate $this->data in my model instead of the $this_data variable I've been using?  What would be the best practice?

Comment: Well, if both functions you're using are in the same Class, then yes, they both have access to the data variable within that class via `$this->data`... It's a bit confusing, though, when you use the same function names for all three of your example functions.

Comment: No, they are not in the came class.  Sorry, my question assumes one has an understanding of the CakePHP framework.  To clarify, the first function is in a Controller class and the second is in a Model class in a MVC architecture.  I almost always name the methods similarly if not exacly the same, so that my code is self documenting.  I guess I'm reaching out to the CakePHP-heads out there for the answer to the $this->data question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea,but unfortunately you have to pass `$this->data` as a parameter because controller and model in cake are extended from diffrent parent-objects.So `$this->data` has diffrent meanings in them.In controller,`$data` attribute is for get POST data while it's a container for the model’s fetched data [in model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/441/data).And I suggest you to read the source code in 
`app/cake/lib/controller/controller.php`

and

`app/cake/lib/model/model.php`

That would make you more clear.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do however is :

In your controller

```
$this->Model->create($this->data);
$this->set('data', $this->Model->some_action());
```

That way, you can access your model data using $this->data in your Model::some_action();

Comment: That Was Perfecto!  I don't wanna take the points away from SpawnCxy Who I marked correct 3 days ago, otherwise this would definitely be my pick.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean ? It will change your model $id to the $data['Model']['id'] value, if that was your concern.